# Finding the angle $θ$ s.t the object will have maximum acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I am trying to calculate the angle $θ$, Such that the given object will have maximal horizonal acceleration.

I have tried to use newton's second law:

We know that $\sum f = ma$, and:

$\sum f = mg\sin(θ)$, And thus:

$mg\sin(θ) = ma \rightarrow g\sin(θ) = a$, And for $θ = 90^{celcius}$ we get $a = g$.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find component of $mg$ force along the inclined plane:
It will be $mg\sin\theta$

Now find component of this force ($mg\sin\theta$) along horizontal and vertical direction.

[image: diagram]

Acceleration in horizontal direction will be = $g\sin\theta\cos\theta$

Therefore,

$$a=g\sin\theta\cos\theta$$
Now,
$$\frac{da}{d\theta}=g\cos2\theta$$
For maximum value of $a$:
$$g\cos2\theta=0$$
$$2\theta=90^{\circ}$$
$$\theta=45^{\circ}$$

Answer (score 1):

Given that, a, (down the incline) = g sin(θ), then the horizontal component of, a, $a_h$ = a cos(θ) = g sin(θ) cos(θ).  Maximize by setting the derivative equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are calculating the component of the acceleration in the direction of movement (i.e along the inclined plane) and not the horizontal direction (i.e along the floor).